# jquery validation , when input field has a title attribute , instead of error message title is given as the error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

hi i am using jquery validation plugin .

i have a strange issue , i have a validaion like this

```
jQuery("#profile_info").validate({

    rules : {
        city : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 3,
            maxlength : 30,
            cityvalidation: true
        },
        state : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 3,
            maxlength : 30,
            cityvalidation: true
        }
    },
    messages : {
        city : {
            required : " City must be  filled in",
            minlength : "At least 3 characters long",
            maxlength : "Should not exceed 30 characters",
        },
        state : {
            required : " State must be  filled in",
            minlength : "At least 3 characters long",
            maxlength : "Should not exceed 30 characters",
        }
    }
});
```

and `cityvalidation`

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("cityvalidation", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\`\.\"\']+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
    }, "You Have Typed Unallowed Charactors");
```

my input fields are

```
                                                    <div class="select-date-container-side location-codes">
                                                        <input id="city" name="city"
                                                            value="<?php if(isset($profileinfo['CityName'])){echo $profileinfo['CityName'];}else if(isset($city)){echo $city;} ?>"
                                                            title="City" type="text"
                                                            class="smaler-textfield textfield clear-default"
                                                            tabindex="1900" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="select-date-container-middle location-codes">
                                                        <input id="state" name="state"
                                                            value="<?php if(isset($profileinfo['StateName'])){echo $profileinfo['StateName'];}else if(isset($state)){echo $state;} ?>"
                                                            title="State" type="text"
                                                            class="smaler-textfield textfield clear-default"
                                                            tabindex="1900" />
                                                    </div>
```

if the `cityvalidation` failed . `"You Have Typed Unallowed Charactors"` message , but instead of that the titles of the fields are shown .

[image]

- if i remove the title it works perfectly . so what i suppoesed to do . i want to get the custom error message instead of title . please help........

thanks in advance .....................

Answer (score 28, accepted):

hmmm i found it .

i used  `ignoreTitle: true,`

```
jQuery("#profile_info").validate({


    ignoreTitle: true,

    rules : {
        city : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 3,
            maxlength : 30,
            cityvalidation: true
        },
        state : {
            required : true,
            minlength : 3,
            maxlength : 30,
            cityvalidation: true
        }
    },
    messages : {
        city : {
            required : " City must be  filled in",
            minlength : "At least 3 characters long",
            maxlength : "Should not exceed 30 characters",
        },
        state : {
            required : " State must be  filled in",
            minlength : "At least 3 characters long",
            maxlength : "Should not exceed 30 characters",
        }
    }
});
```