# jquery validator group - how to use it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 3 fields and button:

```
<input type="text" id="a" />
<input type="text" id="b" />
<input type="text" id="c" />
<input type="button" id="d" />
<label for="all_fields" class="error" style="display:none;">Please fill exactly one field</label>
```

I want to use jquery validator plugin in order to validate that exactly one field filled with text. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: best way is to read its documentation.

Comment: @undefined: I have read the documentation. There isn't a lot about groups. Do you have any direct link with help about group?

Comment: @Naor I can give you a separate demo to show you how can you group the inputs, but it will not be exactly same as what you got above. will that be cool ?

Comment: @Tats_innit: It will be great!

Comment: @Naor hope post below helps, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working demo** `for A / B / C` case: http://jsfiddle.net/hfLwB/

Behaviour: As long as one of the input field is set with nu,her value it will allow the calculation to happen, If all the 3 fields are empty it will thtourgh an error. You will also notice class `.at_least_one` **and** addMthod: `require_from_group`.

Anyhoo code should speak better.

Good link: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Hope it helps :)

**HTML**

```html
<form action="results.whatever" target="_blank" id="HULK">

    <div style="clear:both">
    <label for="a">A</label>
    <div style="float:right">
            <input name="a" type="text" class="at_least_one idleField"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both">
        <label for="b">B</label>
        <div style="float:right">
            <input name="b" type="text" class="at_least_one idleField">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both">
        <label for="c">C</label>
        <div style="float:right">
            <input name="c" type="text" class="at_least_one idleField">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="button">
        <input name="" type="submit" value="Calculate" class="calc_button" style="cursor:hand">
    </div>
    </form>
<div id="errorContainer">
    <h4>errors</h4>
    <ol>
    </ol>
</div>
```

​
**Code**

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
  var numberRequired = options[0];
  var selector = options[1];
  var fields = $(selector, element.form);
  var filled_fields = fields.filter(function() {
    // it's more clear to compare with empty string
    return $(this).val() != ""; 
  });
  var empty_fields = fields.not(filled_fields);
  // we will mark only first empty field as invalid
  if (filled_fields.length < numberRequired && empty_fields[0] == element) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
// {0} below is the 0th item in the options field
}, jQuery.format("Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));

$(document).ready(function(){
  var container = $('#errorContainer');
  $("#HULK").validate(  {

    // We must to force validation of entire form because
    // when we remove value from 2-nd field 
    // the 1-st field becomes invalid.
    onfocusout: function() { $("#HULK").valid() },
    onkeyup: function() { $("#HULK").valid() },

    rules: {
      // note: you can use variable to avoid repeating 
      // of the same code
      a: { 
        number: true,
        require_from_group: [1, ".at_least_one"]
      },
      b: {
        number: true,
        require_from_group: [1,".at_least_one"]
      },
      c: {
        number: true,
        require_from_group: [1,".at_least_one"]
      }
    },
    success: function(label) {  
      label.html(" ").addClass("checked"); 
    },
    errorContainer: container,
    errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container),
    wrapper: 'li',
    meta: "validate"
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Tata_innit, your version of require_from_group is also a bug fix!

Comment: Hasn't the built-in `require_from_group` method been fixed in the latest version?  I think it was.

Comment: @Sparky `:)` The git pull request was based on the solution mentioned in this post I reckon and yes it is fixed `B-)`

Answer (score 3):

Just to add more props to @Tats_innit post.

There is an open issue on github for the 1.10.0 released version of `require_from_group` in `additional-method-1.10.js` for `jquery.validation`.

**github issue:
[require_from_group disables other rules](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412)**

smileyanp@github quoted this post in his solution where he reused @Tats_innit's function and created a [test](http://jsfiddle.net/hfLwB/4/) that showed it works correctly **and doesn't disable** validation on other rules defined prior to the `require_from_group`.

This post is here as a time saver as this burned 3 hrs of googling for such a small detail..

**FIX:**

Just update `additional-method-1.10.js` or execute this code after `additional-method-1.10.js` has loaded (to overwrite the function).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
  var numberRequired = options[0];
  var selector = options[1];
  var fields = $(selector, element.form);
  var filled_fields = fields.filter(function() {
    // it's more clear to compare with empty string
    return $(this).val() != ""; 
  });
  var empty_fields = fields.not(filled_fields);
  // we will mark only first empty field as invalid
  if (filled_fields.length < numberRequired && empty_fields[0] == element) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
// {0} below is the 0th item in the options field
}, jQuery.format("Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));
```

Comment: I am Tats_innit & Good to see the solution went in as a fix `:)` +1 for this!

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to use require_from_group for a magento site yet couldn't get it to work at all, even with this fix.  After wasting far too many hours, I narrowed it down to magento using the title attribute in its html.  I then came across this [jquery validation , when input field has a title attribute , instead of error message title is given as the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292602/jquery-validation-when-input-field-has-a-title-attribute-instead-of-error-me).

I hope this helps others save time!!

Comment: This might be good in its own entry on Stackoverflow. You could as a question and then answer your own question. It would be good to supply code if you can, though, not just links.

Comment: I do think linking to another stack overflow discussion is appropriate. That discussion is about this specific point to which readers should refer for more detail. Repetition leads to transcription errors.